# In Flutter, how do we pull a document from a queue at a certain index?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say I have a queue in a firebase collection, and I want to access the 50th item to the 100th item in that queue. How would I do that? It seems I can only access the queue from the front.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries are not index based. So to read the n<sup>th</sup> document from a collection, you'll need to:

1. Create a query that orders on a certain field or key.
2. Read the first N documents by calling `limit()`.
3. Ignore the first N-1 documents.

The only alternative way to do this is to store the index in each document, which is known as a ranking (because of its most frequent use in leaderboards). For more on how to do that, see [Leaderboard ranking with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720997/leaderboard-ranking-with-firebase)

Comment: after we ignore the first n-1 documents how do we access the documents after that? Not sure how to hold that place in line for the queue