Modeling a game leaderboard with Firestore - does this count as a monotonically increasing field?
I have a video game model where I have a User collection in Firestore where each document has a score field. I want to query to get all users sorted by their score, from highest score to lowest. To do this, I need to index the score field and then I can query all users sorted by their score.
The issue is that the documentation says to avoid creating documents with a monotonically increasing field, like a timestamp, at a very high rate. Does this limitation apply to my use case? Just like timestamps, the score fields are always increasing across documents. But unlike timestamps, the score fields increase at a staggered rate.
For example, one user may have their score go from 1 to 2 to 3 in a one minute period, while another users score may go from 4 to 5 to 6 in that same period of time. Some users play the game often so they may have much larger scores that update more frequently than users who play less often.
Does the limitation to writing/updating documents with monotonically increasing fields apply to my use case?

Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720997/leaderboard-ranking-with-firebase, which deals with how to implement a leaderboard using Firestore? The top answer there is from the Firestore product manager at the time, so is pretty certain to be authoritative.


Does the limitation to writing/updating documents with monotonically increasing fields apply to my use case?

Yes, it applies.  It has to do with the rate of additions within a particular range of values that must be managed by a partitioned index.  If you write heavily within a partitioned range, that partition will get overloaded and have to be re-partitioned repeatedly to handle the load.  The current size of the range of the partition doesn't matter.

But for my score model, not all documents update the same range at the same time (unlike a timestamp). It will naturally be staggered (the document values and ranges being updated at a given time will vary greatly). The only thing is all those values will be increasing monotonically as a users score increases from playing the game more.

Only you can know (or measure, or guess) if your field updates are truly monotonic, in actual practice, inasmuch as it affects the load on an index on that field.  Staggering might help distribute the load, but the specific load on a single partition is the only thing that really matters for the purpose of the documented limit.  Since you aren't afforded visibility into the partitioning of an index and is load history over time, the only wise this to do is assume the worst.
