Rank of a document in firebase sorted collection
I am implementing a leaderboard where the users can see the top 10 users with highest points. This is easily doable by ordering the users collection with points and fetching the top 10. But I'd also like the user to see their own position in the leaderboard, one user's position could be #627, so it won't appear on the top 10 leaderboard, nevertheless showing them their current position #627 in the leaderboard would be a good idea.
Is there any way in firebase where I can find the ordering of a specific document?
Thanks
One way would be to keep fetching more data until the user appears, but it would be costly (both time and money) and may need to lookup the entire users collection.

There is no simple way to do this. See the duplicate for some common options.

For this specific use-case you can nowadays use a count query to (more cheaply) determine a user's position on the leaderboard. This specific answer to the question Doug linked, mentions that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72043234
